# Problem acessing server on docker container

Tags: docker

I am trying to build and run docker image from example on this site: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/hello-minikube/

```
//server.js
var http = require('http');

var handleRequest = function(request, response) {
   console.log('Received request for URL: ' + request.url);
   response.writeHead(200);
   response.end('Hello World!');
};
var www = http.createServer(handleRequest);
www.listen(8080);


//Dockerfile
FROM node:6.14.2
EXPOSE 8080
COPY server.js .
CMD node server.js
```

I use commands

```
docker build -t nsj .
docker run nsj
```

They run without error but I cannot access the server on localhost:8080.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like at least two things are wrong:

1. You need to map the port from your docker host
2. You need to bind your server to 0.0.0.0

So, probably these changes (untested):

In your code:

```
www.listen(8080, "0.0.0.0");
```

In your docker command:

```
docker run nsj -p 8080:8080
```

Note that having `EXPOSE 8080` in your `Dockerfile` does not actually expose anything. It just "marks" this port in the docker engine's metadata and is intended for both documentation (so people reading the `Dockerfile` know what it does) and for tools that inspect the docker engine.

To quote from the [reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose):

> The EXPOSE instruction does not actually publish the port. It
>   functions as a type of documentation between the person who builds the
>   image and the person who runs the container, about which ports are
>   intended to be published

Comment: docker run nsj -p 8080:8080 - worked. But i have EXPOSE 8080 in the dockerfile. Is it not enough? Is it possible to configure it in Dockerfile?

Comment: I updated the answer to explain that bit as well. There is no way for the Dockerfile to "control" the host in that way. Port mapping and volume mounting should be done "from the outside".